# How to filter a gallery using Colorbox?

Tags: jquery, filter, colorbox, quicksand

I've gone through the suggested "Similar Questions," but I didn't see anything I understood as relevant.

I'm using Colorbox to power my online portfolio. I'd like to add a filter (branding, web, print, etc). I found [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/) combined with Quicksand would be a lovely effect, but it utilizes listing and my gallery functions through class. Is there a way to make these functions coexist?

Site: [ephelan.com](http://ephelan.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at using ColorBox's **rel** element?  From the plugin's doc-o:

> This can be used as an anchor rel alternative for ColorBox. This
>   allows the user to group any combination of elements together for a
>   gallery, or to override an existing rel so elements are not grouped
>   together.

```
$("a.gallery").colorbox({rel:"group1"});
```

Note this is not exactly a filter, rather a grouping method so you'd need separate links to trigger the plugin for the various collections.

Also - unrelatedly - the *portfolio.html* page protrudes down over the footer for me) I'm using Chromium on Ubuntu 12 just now) It is the Design Culture Now element.  If you need a screenshot, let me know.

KJM

Comment: I'm curious how multiple rel attributes will affect the gallery. I'll try that first. Also, I would love a screenshot.

Comment: I had tested locally with IE8, but I don't remember that problem. I'll check my margins and padding again. Thank you for all the help, including the screenshots!